# How much would be too much data to save in a public mapping?

Tags: solidity, mapping

So I know that in solidity for larger data we wouldn't use contract to save the data but rather we'd use some kind of external database.
But I'm not sure how large is too large and what would happen if we do save large amount of data just for the sake of user view.

So for for example a mapping `mapping(uint256 => uint256) public Vals` with a thousand `uint256` values. would that be too much of data to save just for users view? How should i know if it actually is too much data or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, you can store as much data as you want in them without encountering an issue.

The problem is that setting these values can be very expensive, even if you use  a `for` loop to set multiple values in a single function call.

The cost of setting a single mapping value would remain somewhat constant, but you'd have to make a lot of transactions that will add up in gas fees.

You can play around in Remix to view gas costs associated with different `mapping` interactions.

For example:

```
contract MappingGas {

    mapping(uint => uint) public values;


    // sets x number of values
    function setMapValues(uint x) public {
        for(uint i; i <= x; i++) {
            values[i] = 7;
        }
    }
}
```

`setMapValues()` gas results by input using the [Etherscan gas tracker](https://etherscan.io/gastracker) as a reference:

When passed `1`:

```js
gas 30580 gas
transaction cost    26591 gas 
execution cost  5387 gas
```

At the time of writing this, it is `0.00036696` ETH at a gas cost of 12 GWEI ($0.61)

When passed `10`:

```js
gas 56093 gas
transaction cost    48776 gas 
execution cost  27572 gas
```

At the time of writing this, it is `0.000673116` ETH at a gas cost of 12 GWEI ($1.12)

When passed `100`:

```js
gas 311220 gas
transaction cost    270626 gas 
execution cost  249422 gas
```

At the time of writing this, it is `0.00373464` ETH at a gas cost of 12 GWEI ($6.20)

When passed `1000`:

```js
gas 2862509 gas
transaction cost    2489138 gas 
execution cost  2467922 gas
```

At the time of writing this, it is `0.034350108` ETH at a gas cost of 12 GWEI ($57)

Depending on your desired effect, you may be happy with storing the data directly inside a mapping like this, otherwise you'd want to use another method to store data off-chain to bypass these gas costs. One example of this is using [Merkle Trees](https://solidity-by-example.org/app/merkle-tree/) to store a single `bytes` object with your Merkle Root.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, so just to i be sure i should only be worried about writing gas? if say i be ok with the gas to write the mapping there will be no other issues with saving large amount of data in a contract. also

Comment: @Thematador Yes, reading from your contract won't cost your EOA user's anything, so if the price of storing all your variables isn't an issue for you, you should be okay.